# Extract text inside within span of webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to extract the delivery status from a website so that I can then live display this status in asp gridview.

I am trying to do this via regex but when trying to set the string value i am having issues.

This is the raw format of the html:

`<span class=" palette-confirm "> Delivered </span>`

```
(<span class=")\s+(palette-confirm)(\n|\r)(">)(\n|\r)\s+
```

I have come up with the above in regex101 but when i try and use this in a string in visual studio the syntax is not right.

```
string pattern = "(<span class=\")\s+(palette-confirm)(\n |\r)(\">)(\n|\r)\s+\";
```

al unsure how to then take out the last  tag so i only extract the 'Delivered' text.

Comment: raw format of html is:
<span class="                             palette-confirm
">
                Delivered
            </span>

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the backslash is treated as an escape character. In order to keep the backslash for the regex, you either need to write double backslashes `"()(\\n|\\r)\\s+\\"` or tell C# to not treat the backslash as an escape character by putting an @ symbol in front of your string: `@"()(\n|\r)\s+\"`.

Comment: ok thats brilliant thanks for clearing that up. what about if there are quotation marks within the string as well? is that the same escape character?

Comment: In that case, you'd use the backslash as an escape character (so no @ in front), e.g. `"\"test\""`.

Answer (score 0):

How many statuses are there? Just match via the actual status text via or's `|`.....

```
 \>\s*(Delivered | In\sProcess)\s*\<
```

Here is an example:

```
var pattern = @"\>\s*(Delivered | In\sProcess)\s*\<";

var str = @"<span class="" palette-confirm ""> In Process</span?";

var result = Regex.Match(str, pattern );

Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[1].Value);
```

**Output**

```
In Process
```